# How to toggle the vertical jQuery.mmenu submenus?

Tags: jquery, css, mmenu

i am trying since days to get this right: 
the submenus of the jQuery.mmenu shall toggle smoothly and i always would like just one submenu being open at a time. Also i like to keep the feature that if a page opens the current menu element is visible.

I did set up a [js fiddle](http://goo.gl/1NA5Cw) here.

Maybe someone can get me a hint how to apply the .next() selector - in case that is the way to go...

i managed to create a slide toggle, but it toggles all submenus of course:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mm-vertical ul.level2").hide();
  $(".mm-vertical ul.level3").hide();
  $(".level1 a.mm-next").click(function () {
    $(".mm-vertical ul.level2").slideToggle("slow", function () {});
  });
  });
```

Comment: What about to use another plugin ? 
http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-treeview/

Or you want to use that plugin?

Comment: i´d like to keep that, because i am almost finished with the css and all. just got stuck with those slide toggle of the submenus. Thnaks for the recommendation anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it myself. Not very elegant or short but it works well and keeps the submenu open in case it contains the current menu item. the solution is limited to 3 levels. I added the classes "level1", "level2" as i generate the html of the menu via typo3.

```
$(".mm-vertical ul").hide();
$(".mm-vertical ul.level3").hide();


$(".level1 a.mm-next").on('click', function(){
var element = $(this).parent('li');
if (element.hasClass('mm-opened')) {
    element.find('ul.level2').slideUp("slow", function () {});
    }
    else {
        element.find('ul.level2').slideDown("slow", function () {});
        element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp("slow", function () {});
        element.siblings('li').removeClass('mm-opened');
        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('mm-opened');
        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp("slow", function () {});
        }
          });

$(".level2 a.mm-next").on('click', function(){
var element = $(this).parent('li');
if (element.hasClass('mm-opened')) {
    element.find('ul.level3').slideUp("slow", function () {});
    }
    else {
        element.find('ul.level3').slideDown("slow", function () {});
                element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp("slow",   function () {});
        element.siblings('li').removeClass('mm-opened');
        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('mm-opened');
        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp("slow", function () {});
        }
          });
 $('.level2.mm-selected').each(function(){
$(this).parent().removeAttr("style");
});
$('.level2.mm-opened').each(function(){
$(this).parent().removeAttr("style");
 var element = $('.level2.mm-opened');
 element.find('ul.level3').removeAttr("style");
 });
$('.level3.mm-selected').each(function(){
$(this).parent().removeAttr("style");
});
$('.level3.mm-opened').each(function(){
$(this).parent().removeAttr("style");



});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
        offCanvas: true,
        extensions  : [ "position-right", "listview-50", "fx-panels-slide-up", "fx-listitems-drop", "border-offset" ],
    });
```

This will help to slide up jQuery mmenus > submenus